# Pandas groupby ignores column created with apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

Executing this code below gives a strange result. Essentially the column inserted through apply gets ignored when the dataframe is stitched back together to give the final result. Why is that and how can i get the result I want?

```py
# initialization and dataframe generation
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[['one', 'one', 'two', 'two'],
                                             ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']])))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((3,4)), columns=index)
```

```py
# actual code starts here
def new_zero(df):
    df.loc[:,(df.columns[0][0],'zero')] = 0      # MultiIndex column label necessary
    display(df) 
    return df

dd = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(new_zero)
dd
```

[image]

If I switch rows and columns, it works. (Though level 0 of the index is duplicated):

```py
def new_zero(df):
    df.loc[(df.index[0][0],'zero'),:] = 0
    display(df)
    return df

dd = df.T.groupby(level=0, axis=0).apply(new_zero)
dd
```

Comment: What is the result you want? What would the df look like in correct form?

Comment: The correct form should have 6 columns. one: foo, bar, zero and two: foo, bar, zero

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is up with your code, but I would take a different approach:

1. You can loop through the `one` and `two` column names
2. Then, create a new multi-index column with `df[col, 'zero'] = 0`.
3. Finally, to reorganize the columns as desired, you can use `.sort_index()` and pass `axis=1`:

---

```
    import pandas as pd
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[['one', 'one', 'two', 'two'],
                                             ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']])))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((3,4)), columns=index)
cols = list(set([col[0] for col in df.columns]))
for col in cols:
    df[col, 'zero'] = 0
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=[0, 1])
df = df[[('one',  'foo'),
         ('one',  'bar'),
         ('one', 'zero'),
         ('two',  'foo'),
         ('two',  'bar'),
         ('two', 'zero')]]
df
Out[1]: 
  one          two         
  foo bar zero foo bar zero
0   0   1    0   2   3    0
1   4   5    0   6   7    0
2   8   9    0  10  11    0
```

Comment: Thanks! The first issue with this solution is that it doesn’t explain the strange behavior of apply, which is really my core concern. Is it a bug or do I just not understand it. If it’s a bug I might present it to the pandas GitHub community. The second issue with this solution is that I lose control over the order of columns because of the sort function. I know, in this case zero ends up at the end, but let’s suppose it’s a different column name that wouldn’t be automatically sorted to the end.

Comment: @Jim yeah, I don't know what the issue with your code is either but this solution gives the expected output. I have included an extra line of code that shows you how you can reorganize multi-index columns to your liking.